# Geometry of 2-arrows

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, higher-category-theory

It is frequently said that one of the contributions of Grothendieck to geometry was to systematically think about the properties of morphisms, as opposed to the properties of spaces themselves (the latter could then be recovered as the properties of the structure morphism). In a sense, this means instead of thinking about objects, we think about arrows.

Does this philosophy have an incarnation in the world of higher mathematics? Can we talk about the geometric properties of arrows between arrows, arrows between arrows between arrows, etc.? Maybe one answer would be "$n$-stacks" but I never really saw much serious geometry done with them. I think that SAG/DAG has nothing to do with this question but correct me if I am wrong.

I have heard that $(\infty, 2)$-categories are less understood than $(\infty, 1)$-categories, maybe this is relevant to this question.

Comment: DAG is definitely the place to talk about morphisms between morphisms etc. I don't think this grew out of the relative POV, rather out of the observation that certain moduli problems are naturally valued in categories (and higher cats). Ofc one could ask if the relative POV (which translates verbatim) is used in DAG and the answer is "yes, all the time, to the point at which it goes without saying". Whether DAG has produced serious geometry is another question, but imo the answer is definitely positive.

Comment: @EBz from my understanding, there is "higher" stuff and there is "derived" stuff and those two are logically independent (though you can combine them if you want). Can you clarify?

Comment: @op,  think of schemes as the functors they represent, then "higher" typically means one enlarges the target category. I agree that this isn't really DAG (in which one enlarges both source and target) . So, at least to me, higher instances of the relative point of view would just be "relative POV for higher stacks". For these u can define etale etc etc. Judging by your question in the comments to the answer below tho, this is maybe not quite the question you wanted to ask. Sorry if this is not of help.!

Comment: @EBz but I think DAG is not about enlarging source and target in some random way, it is actually a fairly specific way (and this way is distinct from what one does in higher geometry). For example, in some papers of Toen he maintains a crystal clear distinction between "higher" and "derived", thus my reluctance to believe that DAG is relevant to higher morphisms.

Comment: Well as u say "higher stacks" and "higher derived stacks" are indeed different and the question indeed doesn't have much to do with DAG (beyond the fact that DAG papers tend to develop a lot of potentially useful higher mathematics). That being said, if u want an answer to connect to the world of higher mathematics, I don't see how higher stacks are avoidable, as to me these two worlds are basically the same. ie a "higher X" is gotten by recipe, "think of X as a representable set valued functor and enlarge target category to spaces not just sets". Maybe a more specific question would help?

Comment: @EBz I think we understand each other now. I agree that taken at the face value, "higher stacks" are unavoidable in an answer to this question. It is just that the mathematics done by people who use that term (sort of "the culture" associated with this term) does not seem particularly geometric to me. If you have a counterexample, that might qualify as an answer.

Comment: @op, wrt geometry and higher stacks, I'm very fond of Carlos Simpson's works, for example https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510269. Also there is, iirc, a research project (Simpson Toën Pantev Katzarkov) on non abelian hodge theory where HAG features heavily. Nb that here higher stacks feature as *coefficients* for cohomology theories, there's a talk by Toën where this pov is outlined but I can't remember it off the top of my head

Answer (score 6):

As I have understood it (though I’m neither an algebraic geometer nor a historian) the novelty of Grothendieck that you’re describing was **considering morphisms as representing families of objects varying over a base, and taking such families of objects as a main focus of development** (rather than just individual objects).

This idea is a pervasive and crucial ingredient in all the approaches to “higher mathematics” that I know of.  In Lurie’s development, for instance, it shows up as the various notions of “fibration” that appear (sometimes as the main objects of study, sometimes as auxiliary technical tools); in the frequent use of slice categories, codomain fibrations, and so on; and many other places.  (Though the question suggests that perhaps Lurie’s development isn’t the kind of direction you’re thinking of; if so, could you clarify which approaches you are more interested in?)

So there’s hardly a question of “can this concept be studied in the higher-categorical setting” — it’s hard to imagine developments of higher-categorical mathematics *without* this concept.

Comment: indeed, I do not deny that $\infty$-category theory, developed among others by Lurie, is essential as a language for an answer to this question. But is there a notion of a proper $2$-morphism? Smooth $2$-morphism? Etale $2$-morphism?

Comment: Using the functor of points approach, a scheme is a functor, so a morphism of schemes is a natural transformation, so.... (You need all sorts of machinery to talk about proper/smooth/étale etc, it's not automatic from the category axioms. So this stuff needs to be set up first.)

Comment: @DavidRoberts yes Sir, that I understand. But has somebody set up this machinery? Any references? That was the question to some extent, I think.

Comment: Not that I know of!